# Endless PageAdapter for ViewPager takes centuries to load a new page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to implement a similar feature that Google Calendar has.

Basically, I have two views:

- **View A)**
  ViewPager with CustomViews of calendars. Let's call this `MonthViewPager` which extends `ViewPager`
- **View B)**
  -- On the top of the ViewPager -- a Year View which says what month the `View A)` has to go. Let's call this `YearView`.

**Scope:** I want the user to be able to "infinitely" scroll along the months desired, and being able to switch month from the `YearView`.

The way I initialize my ViewPager is this:

```
public MonthViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    this.attrs = attrs;
    setAdapter(new EndLessAdapter(Calendar.getInstance()));
    setCurrentItem(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);
}
```

which takes this performance:

[image]

I've been alternating the number of the pages kept offscreen in an idle state with `setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)`. I've tried with 1, 3, 12...

My `PagerAdapter` is this one:

```
public class EndLessAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Calendar calendar;
    public EndLessAdapter(Calendar calendar) {
        this.calendar = calendar;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public CalendarView instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + position - Integer.MAX_VALUE/2);

        final CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(context, attrs);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(calendarView, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        return calendarView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

but then when I want to set a month from `YearView` (for example December), if you see my adapter, I set the position `8 + Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2` which is `8 + April`

I do it like:

```
    int differenceMonths = Utils.differenceMonthsToNow(date);
    monthViewPager.setCurrentItem(differenceMonths + Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2, false);
```

and this is the performance:

[image]

the UI gets blocked for all that time.

I debugged everything with the `Android Monitor`, and I saw that 99.0% of the time was taking time on:

`ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll)`:

[image]

and that the method `instantiateItem` is calling every single view. (I think it shouldn't be like this and maybe it's a bug).

- Alternatively I tried to embed everything on a `Fragment` and change `PageAdapter` by `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` but the result was really similar.

What's going on with my code? Isn't it possible to skip, for example, 1000 pages without avoiding to draw each one?

Thanks to have taken the whole reading ;).

Answer (score 1):

`setCurrentItem(int)` uses a smooth scroll, so that means that it will scroll through ALL the views until it arrives on the one that you asked for, so that means that all the views have to be drawn.

> Isn't it possible to skip, for example, 1000 pages without avoiding to draw each one?

well, the solution here would be to make it without the scroll, `setCurrentItem(int, false);` that way the ViewPager will only draw that item and skip all the items in-between.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I feel sorry I haven't written that on my question. Yes, in fact the `smoothScroll` is equals to `false` since I tried to see every method. I'm going to edit my question. Thanks for spotting it!